# Perform sum of values then getting rid of decimals SAP WEBI report

Tags: business-objects, webi

On my WebI report, I will have multiple textboxes, inside of those textboxes will be a formula to extract data by `CALTIME` and `CALTIME2` like below:

```
Formula for MONTH = [MONEY] WHERE ([TYPE] = "Month" And [CALTIME] = "CONDITION1" AND [CALTIME2] = "CONDITION2")
Formula for Year = [MONEY] WHERE ([TYPE] = "Year" And [CALTIME] = "CONDITION1" AND [CALTIME2] = "CONDITION2")
```

My purpose is, if the TYPE is "Month", we will perform the sum of all related values and remove all the decimal places. If the TYPE is "Year", we will remove all the  decimal places of the value, then perform the sum of all decimal-removed-values.

Example with below data, I want to calculate for CALTIME = 201712 and CALTIME2 = 201708, I will have the following results:

```
TYPE = Month = 2062.91666 + 2062.91666 + 2062.91666 = 6188.74998 = 6188
TYPE = Year = 2062 + 2062 + 2062 = 6186
```

But actually what I'm getting at my WEBI report is:

```
TYPE = Month = 2062+ 2062 + 2062 = 6186
TYPE = Year = 2062 + 2062 + 2062 = 6186
```

Source Table : DataTbl

```
CALTIME CALTIME2    TYPE    MONEY
201712  201708     Month    2062.91666
201712  201708     Month    2062.91666
201712  201708     Month    2062.91666
201712  201708     Year     2062.91666
201712  201708     Year     2062.91666
201712  201708     Year     2062.91666
```

My dimensions: CALTIME,CALTIME2,TYPE

> CALTIME : DataTbl.CALTIME
> CALTIME2 :    DataTbl.CALTIME2
> TYPE : DataTbl.TYPE

My measure : MONEY (Only one)

> 1. Projection function : None
> 2. SQL : `Cast(SUM(Case when DataTbl.TYPE = 'Month' then DataTbl.MONEY else Cast(DataTbl.MONEY as integer) end) as integer)`

Is this possible to achieve what I want just by declaring measure's options  in the Universe?

I can't edit all the textboxes on the WEBI reports since there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here `SQL : Cast(SUM(Case when DataTbl.TYPE = 'Month' then DataTbl.MONEY else Cast(DataTbl.MONEY as integer) end) as integer)` instead of type casting `DataTbl.MONEY` ,first sum the money and then type cast it .
2nd option (Universe side):
You can try creating an object with the same defination as the variable "month" and "year".
Here do the sum first and then try typecasting the datatype of the object in the universe or at report level .
Hope this solves your problem